# Стремится разбежаться или стремиться разбежаться

Tags: глаголы

Верно ли употребление мягкого знака?

Comment: Могут употребляться оба варианта. **Но в разных контекстах.** А какой у Вас?

Comment: внимание и сосредоточенность будут стремиться разбежаться в разные стороны...

Comment: Ну, если в сочетании с **_будут_**, то нужен инфинитив: _будут **стремиться**..._

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы определить, нужен ли ***ь***, достаточно задать соответствующий вопрос.

- Если глагол отвечает на вопрос ***что делать, ь*** в глаголе нужен.
- А если на вопрос ***что делает*** (или ***делается***), пишем *без **ь**.*

Comment: как правило, мне попадались такие парные глаголы, где у первого - нет мягкого знака, а у второго - есть!

Comment: Всё правильно! Например: *Мне хочется разбежаться.* Со мной что делается? Мне хочется. Хочется что сделат**ь**? Разбежат**ь**ся.

Comment: Если глаголы парные, то от первого ко второму и не задашь вопрос "что делает?", только "что делать?", поэтому второй и получается всегда с Ь. Почему первый без Ь, мне сложно чётко обосновать, но часто к нему вопрос от подлежащего, а его по другому и не задашь. Могут быть три глагола подряд, например, *нужно постараться разбежаться как следует.*

Comment: @shampar А чем Вам строчный жирный Ь не понравился? Сначала написал такой (как сейчас и как у Вас), но потом показалось, что в ответе **ь** лучше будет смотреться.

Comment: Прибавьте ещё и курсив. Так видно сразу, что это буква (название буквы пишется прописной) да и вообще, чем больше букв с надстрочной частью, тем для глаза текст приятней.

Comment: Вообще, Вы правы, пожалуй. Хотя я считаю, что может быть несколько хороших вариантов. В данном случае мне не очень нравится, что Ь смахивает на латинскую маленькую b. :)

Answer (score 1):

*Внимание и сосредоточенность будут **стремитЬся** разбежаться в разные стороны*.

Вообще-то правильно так (мн. ч. — стремятся):

*Внимание и сосредоточенность* (что дела**ют**?) *стрем**ят**ся* (что сдела**ть**?) *разбежа**ть**ся в разные стороны.*
*Внимание и сосредоточенность будут* (что дела**ть**?) *стреми**тЬ**ся разбежаться в разные стороны.*

Сравните (как у Вас в вопросе, ед. ч.):

*Он* (что дела**ет**?) *стрем**ит**ся разбежаться быстрее всех.*
*Он будет* (что дела**ть**?) *стреми**тЬ**ся разбежаться быстрее всех.*

Или ещё пример:

*Ребёнок* (что дела**ет**?) *уч**ит**ся плавать.*
*Ребёнок будет* (что дела**ть**?) *учи**тЬ**ся плавать.*